# Salvar Nome do Caminho e Nome da Planilha em uma Célula

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macro

Boa tarde,

Pessoal, eu preciso de uma função no VBA que eu possa selecionar um arquivo e gravar o nome do arquivo e caminho dele em duas células. O caminho do arquivo eu consegui, conforme o código abaixo. Mas o nome do arquivo não, alguém pode me ajudar?
Por exemplo:
Célula B2 = C:User/Documents/Vendas.xlsx
Célula C2= Vendas

```
Public Function AbrirArquivo() As String

    Dim Filtro As String
    Dim Titulo_da_Caixa As String
    Dim Arquivo As Variant

    Filtro = "Todos os Arquivos (*.*),"

    Titulo_da_Caixa = "Selecione o arquivo"

    ChDrive ("C")
    ChDir ("C:\")

    With Application

        Filename = .GetOpenFilename(Filtro, 3, Titulo_da_Caixa)

        ChDrive (Left(.DefaultFilePath, 1))
        ChDir (.DefaultFilePath)

    End With

    If Filename = False Then
        MsgBox "Nenhum arquivo foi selecionado."
        Exit Function
    End If

    AbrirArquivo = Filename
    Planilha2.Range("B2") = AbrirArquivo

End Function
```

Desde já, obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Há algumas maneiras de realizar isto, se você já possui a String com o caminho completo da pasta de trabalho `ThisWorkbook.Path`, é possível manipular strings para obter o resultado desejado, como pode ser visto no código a seguir:

```
Dim x As String
x = "C:\User\Documents\Vendas.xlsx"

Dim nomeArquivo As String
nomeArquivo = Right(x, Len(x) - InStrRev(x, "\"))

Debug.Print nomeArquivo 'Vendas.xlsx

Dim nomeArquivosemFormato As String
nomeArquivosemFormato = Left(nomeArquivo, InStrRev(nomeArquivo, ".") - 1)

Debug.Print nomeArquivosemFormato 'Vendas
```

Ou utilizar o [FSO](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object) (FileSystemObject), que é o mais indicado para evitar erros, 
e principalmente por possuir [mais funções](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object) que provavelmente serão utilizadas com o arquivo.

```
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim nomeArquivo As String, nomeArquivosemFormato As String
nomeArquivo = fso.GetFileName("C:\User\Documents\Vendas.xlsx")

Debug.Print nomeArquivo

nomeArquivosemFormato = fso.GetBaseName("C:\User\Documents\Vendas.xlsx")
Debug.Print nomeArquivosemFormato
```

Answer (score 0):

Acrescente, após a linha `Planilha2.Range("B2") = AbrirArquivo` as seguintes linhas em seu código:

```
NomeArquivo = Mid(AbrirArquivo, InStrRev(AbrirArquivo, "\") + 1)
NomeArquivo = Mid(NomeArquivo, 1, InStrRev(NomeArquivo, ".") - 1)
Plan1.Range("C2") = NomeArquivo
```

A função `InStrRev`procura um determinado caracter em uma string, de trás para frente.
A primeira linha procura a última `\` e pega o nome do arquivo mais a extensão.
A segunda linha procura o `.` e retira a extensão.